# Can I put multiple values in object?

Tags: java, arrays, object

I want an object with multiple values and in one value a list of strings.

For example a cookbook:

- The recipes are the objects stored in an arraylist.
- Every object should have a name, a boolean (isVeggie) and a list of all the ingredients and the associated quantities.

I thought of other arraylist inside the object, but I can´t access the list on the object.

```
public String name;
public double cost;
public boolean isClassic;
public boolean isVeggie;
public boolean isVegan;
protected ArrayList<String> ingredients  = new ArrayList<String>();

    
public recipes (String name, double cost, boolean isClassic, boolean isVeggie, boolean isVegan,
        ArrayList<String> ingredients) {
    super();
    this.name = name;
    this.cost = cost;
    this.isClassic = isClassic;
    this.isVeggie = isVeggie;
    this.isVegan = isVegan;
    this.ingredients = ingredients;
```

Comment: What if you make the ingredients list public?

Comment: unfortunately the same result

Comment: I can also fill the list with strings, but I get the same ingredients for each object.

Comment: I don't see a language tag.  Is that Java?

Comment: sorry, yes it is

Comment: Your question is quite confusing and you seem to use "value" when you mean "property". Try to re-write your question with a better example of what you want to achieve and what is impeding you.

Comment: "*but I can´t access the list on the object.*" How are you trying to access the list? Add a getter method and return `ingredients`.

Comment: Is it even possible to store an array list into an object?

Answer (score 2):

Of course you can create arrays or lists as a property inside another object. Consider the following example:

```
public class User {
    private String name;
    private List<String> nicknames;

    public User(String name, List<String> nicknames) {
        this.name = name;
        this.nicknames = nicknames;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public List<String> getNicknames() {
        return nicknames;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setNickNames(List<String> nicknames) {
        this.nicknames = nicknames;
    }
}
```

Class `User` contains a list of nicknames. You can create a `User` object and access it's properties like the following:

```
User user = new User("RealName", Arrays.asList("nickname1", "nickname2"));
List<String> userNicknames = userr.getNicknames();
userNicknames.add("nickname3");
```

Comment: Thank you! Workes well, but how can I add more nicknames in this example?

Comment: please see my edited answer, you can call `userNicknames.add("nickname3");`

Answer (score 0):

## tl;dr

You asked:

> Is it even possible to store an array list into an object?

Yes. Define a member variable like any other, using the type `ArrayList`.

Here we define a `record`. Specify `List` as one of the member fields.

```
public record Recipe ( String name, double cost, boolean isClassic, boolean isVeggie, boolean isVegan, List< String > ingredients ) {}
```

Populate with `List.of`.

```
new Recipe(                     // Defined as `public record Recipe`. 
    "Beans & Rice", 
    0.99d, 
    true , 
    true, 
    true, 
    List.of( "beans", "rice" )  // `List.of` produces an object of type `List` using an unspecified concrete class. 
)
```

Access the list of ingredients.

```
myRecipe.ingredients()
```

## Details

The [Answer by Sergey](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70310479/642706) is correct, and should be accepted. I will add a few thoughts.

### Naming conventions

Mind the naming conventions in Java, as they make your code easier to read. So your class name should start with an uppercase letter. And naming in the singular makes more sense in your case. So: `Recipe`.

### `BigDecimal`

In real work, never use a floating-point type where accuracy matters. Floating-point technology [trades away accuracy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic#Accuracy_problems) for speed of execution.

So for money and such, use [`BigDecimal`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/math/BigDecimal.html) class rather than `double`.

### Polymorphism: Use more general interface/superclass

Define your ingredients list property as the more general interface `List` rather than committing to it always being the concrete class `ArrayList`.

### Unmodifiable list

Populate that ingredients list with an unmodifiable list if you do not intend to allow the calling programmer to make alterations.

### Record

If the primary purpose of your class is to transparently and immutably carry data, then define the class as a [record](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/395). Merely declare your member fields. The compiler implicitly creates the constructor, getters, `equals` & `hashCode`, and `toString`.

Your entire class definition becomes this one line:

```
public record Recipe ( 
    String name, 
    BigDecimal cost, 
    boolean isClassic,  
    boolean isVeggie, 
    boolean isVegan, 
    List<String> ingredients 
) {}
```

### Example

Example usage.

```
Recipe beansAndRice = new Recipe( "Beans & Rice", new BigDecimal( "0.99" ), true , true, true, List.of( "beans", "rice" ) ) ;
```

To access the list of ingredients, call the implicitly generated accessor method whose name is the name of the property (no `get` prefix).

```
List< String > ingredients = beansAndRice.ingredients() ;
```

To make a modifiable copy of the list, pass to constructor of `ArrayList`.

```
List< String > ingredientsToModify = new ArrayList<>( ingredients ) ;
```